# Mixed POST parameters with WCF Web Api

Tags: wcf-web-api

I'm trying to write a service using WCF Web Api (preview 6), which passes in parameters through the route AND through the POST body. (Variable and method names changed to protect the innocent)

For example..

[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "{routeVariableOne}/{routeVariableTwo}/StaticRoute/{postVariableOne}", Method = "POST")]
public ReturnClass AddToCollection(string postVariableOne, string routeVariableOne, string routeVariableTwo)
    {
      //Do things
    }

So, I want to POST postVariableOne data to the url /Resource/routeVariableTwo/routeVariableTwo

When I try posting this

{ "postVariableOne": "New Value" }

Accept:application/json
Content-Type:application/json
Content-Length:31

http://localhost/App/api/Resource/routeVariableOne/routeVariableTwo/StaticRoute

I get Response 500/Internal Server Error. The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.  If I leave out the json post value, it at least hits my breakpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the parameter that corresponds to the body of type ObjectContent, then use the ReadAs() [may need to be ReadAsAsync now] method on that parameter.